# symfony2: trying to update the entities using "doctrine:generate:entities"

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have this file:

```
#src/Jander/JanderBundle/resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm/ 
Propuestas.orm.yml 
Propuestas: 
  type: entity 
  table: propuestas 
  fields: 
    id: 
      id: true 
      type: integer 
      unsigned: false 
      nullable: false 
      generator: 
        strategy: IDENTITY 
    contenido: 
      type: string 
      length: 230 
      fixed: false 
      nullable: false 
  lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

I have just added a new field like this:

```
Propuestas: 
  type: entity 
  table: propuestas 
  fields: 
    id: 
      id: true 
      type: integer 
      unsigned: false 
      nullable: false 
      generator: 
        strategy: IDENTITY 
    contenido: 
      type: string 
      length: 230 
      fixed: false 
      nullable: false 
    contenido2: 
      type: string 
      length: 230 
      fixed: false 
      nullable: false 
  lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

and then I'm trying to generate the entity with the new field and I 
get this:

> $ php app/console doctrine:generate:entities "JanderJanderBundle"
>
> > backing up Propuestas.php to Propuestas.php~ 
> >     generating Volumus\VolumusBundle\Entity\Propuestas

but when I open Propuestas.php there isn't any reference about 
"contenido2".

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried updating your schema first?

Comment: @greg0ire, I'm updating the schema (Propuestas.orm.yml) first, and then try to generate the entity..Or maybe I don't understand your comment..

Comment: schema is a synonym for database. I meant this : `console doctrine:schema:update --force`

Comment: @greg0ire, ok, I did it but it says: "Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.". In the 
 table Propuestas, there is not the new field.

Comment: O_o this is getting very strange... try changing the name of the field to something like "secundo_contenido", just to make sure you're not experiencing what would be a very severe bug in doctrine.

Comment: @greg0ire, I've done it, but after "doctrine:generate:entities" it does not generate "secundo_contenido"..

Comment: @greg0ire, I'm using a bit old version of symfony: 2.0.4 (2011-Dec-04), maybe does it care?

Comment: @greg0ire, I've written the field directly on Propuestas class like this:     /**
     * 8var string $foo
     * 
     * 8ORM\Column(name="foo", type="string", length=40, nullable=false)
     */
    private $foo; and then I execute "php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force" and I get "Nothing to update".

Comment: What happens if you drop and create your schema?

Comment: @greg0ire, after doing what you say (doctrine:database:drop --force/doctrine:schema:create) it create again the schema but the new field that I written by hand in Propuestas class in not created in the schema..Of course, I checked the database is dropped when i do the drop task.

Comment: Could it possibly be a cache problem then?

Comment: Yeah, I cleaned the cache and now its working..Thanks!!

Comment: @greg0ire, anyway, when I try to update the schema (doctrine:schema:update), it's taking as base the yml, instead of the class. I suppose there is a way to create the schema from the class..

Comment: Yeah, you're supposed to choose "annotations" instead of "yaml" somewhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearing the cache solves the problem. This is strange, make sure your cache permissions are fine.